# cannot change windows share permissions on raspberri pi

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi

I have mounted an xp  ntfs share drive on my raspberri pi with the command
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.103/share1 /mnt/mtmy

The only way that I can edit and save files in this directory from raspberri pi  is to use the sudo command.  eg. sudo leafpad etc. Unless I precede  with sudo  I have a permissions problems and cannot save my changes.

I have tried sudo chmod 666 -r * from the mtmy location and I get "permission denied" response as it recurses.   I have also tried sudo chown and got a similar response.

I can access this windows share from other windows machines with no permissions problems so I don't think the problem is related to windows sharing.  However, it appears that not even using sudo can make  the permissions changes in rpi  to grant permission to other users.

Comment: try chmod 777 -r /mnt/mtmy/ (or 666 or whatever you want)

Comment: ok, I got thispi@raspberrypi /mnt $ sudo chmod 777 -r /mnt/myny
chmod: cannot access `777': No such file or directory
chmod: changing permissions of `/mnt/myny': Permission denied

Comment: You have the drive mounted already, yes? Also, there's a / on the end of myny/

Comment: yes, it is definitely mounted and I just tried adding the "/" on the end and it did not make a difference, same fail  message previously posted.  As I said, root can add/del/modify files in /mnt/myny/ but a standard user can only open files to view but cannot save or modify.  And for whatever reason root cannot do a chmod or chown.

Comment: I have since discovered that this problem is not unique to raspberri pi.  I am running debian on a laptop and when I mount that same ntfs network drive only su has rw permission but it does not have authority to run chmod or chown.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible for mounted ntfs permissions to be managed by su.  They only can be managed as part of the mount command.